Stream Firestore to BigQuery Backfill option not appearing
Upon installing the Stream Firestore to BigQuery extension into my Firestore database, the backfill option "Import existing Firestore documents into BigQuery" does not appear on the installation page. Does anyone know if I am missing a configuration perhaps?
I tried reinstalling the extension 2 times, changing the location and checking the documentation with no luck. I am currently unable to run the import script.

The option has been removed for now, while a bug in it is being fixed. You can track progress on that fix here: https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/2029
